# Python KeyError when printing a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a string via stdout in Python which will then be picked up by through a child process in NodeJS. My code is as follows:

```py
sys.stdout.write('{r: {0}, g: {1}, b: {2}, brightness: {3}}'.format(int(result_color.color[0]), int(result_color.color[1]), int(result_color.color[2]), int(current_brightness)))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

but for some reason I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\script.py", line 811, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\..\script.py", line 756, in main
    sys.stdout.write('{r: {0}, g: {1}, b: {2}, brightness: {3}}'.format(int(result_color.color[0]), int(result_color.color[1]), int(result_color.color[2]), int(current_brightness)))
KeyError: 'r'
```

I can surround the keys with a " ' " but then it is not in the correct format to use `JSON.parse()` through JS. Why is it exhibiting this behavior? It can't think of a reason for it to be trying to process it as a dictionary when I'm passing print a string. (I want to process this as a string through Python and an Object once received in JS. A dict shouldn't be involved on Python's endd)

Comment: In the future, check out the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). In particular, its `json.dumps` takes a dict and returns a string that can be parsed by `JSON.parse` on the NodeJS side. This is safer and more readable than string formatting.

Answer (score 3):

`{` and `}` is the key characters in a string template, you have to escape it with `{{` and `}}`, Try

```
sys.stdout.write('{{r: {0}, g: {1}, b: {2}, brightness: {3}}}'.format(int(result_color.color[0]), int(result_color.color[1]), int(result_color.color[2]), int(current_brightness)))
```

You can find more information here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3.x You can use f-string for fomatting, I think it's more readable

```
import sys;

class Color:
  def __init__(self, rgb, brightness):
    self.color = rgb
    self.brightness = brightness;

result_color = Color([11,22,33], 100)    

def show_color(color, brightness):
  [r,g,b] = color;
  sys.stdout.write(f'r: {r}, g: {g}, b: {b}, brightness: {brightness}\n')
  sys.stdout.flush()

show_color(result_color.color, result_color.brightness)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expanded version of my comment. It uses the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. I've also shortened the code so it looks neater and doesn't repeat as much.

```py
import sys
import json

...

r, g, b = map(int, result_color.color)
data = dict(r=r, g=g, b=b)

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(data))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Also, I suggest that you use the normal [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. If you need to not have a newline at the end and you want to flush it, both are parameters you can specify.

```py
print(json.dumps(data), end="", flush=True)
```